# Error cargando script

Tags: javascript, php, script

Buenas colegas tengo una situación en el momento de cargar un proyecto.
El error radica a la hora de cargar los script (librerias).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta la imagen. que muestra el navegador.
Estuve leyendo sobre los typeMimes y no he dado con el error.
Les muestro como tengo el codigo de los enlaces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo destacar que se realiza las solicitudes de carga correctamente con success (200). Pero asigna por defecto el tipo mime (text/html) a los archivos js, arrojando el error que anteriormente comente.

No existen dificultades de permisos entre el proyecto.
Y la verdad estoy parado en esta situación.
Cuando comente que realiza las solicitudes de carga correctamente, es para destacar que no es problema de ubicaciones incorrectas o nombres de carpetas inaccesibles.
Intente asignarle la cabecera en php, y tampoco me funciona.

Agradecería el apoyo Colegas.

Comment: [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Además, sé descriptivo en el título: ¿cuál error?

Comment: Buenas, el titulo indica que el error aparece al tratar de cargar unos script, gracias por las otras sugerencias en próximas preguntas seguiré sus aclaraciones al respecto.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente ese tipo de error tiene que ver con la configuración *del servidor*. Debes revisar la configuración de los tipos MIME en el servidor. Por ejemplo, en Apache, revisa el archivo *apache_home/conf/mime.types* (donde *apache_home* es el directorio en que se instaló apache).

Comment: He revisado cada uno de los ficheros apache, en el caso que mencionas tienen habilitado los tipos mimes de js.

Comment: Aún hay otras cosas que puedes probar: 1) agregar la etiqueta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">` en la página para indicar al navegador el tipo de contenido que tiene que renderizar. 2) Asegurarte de que los archivos js no contengan código html (no creo que esta sea la causa pero a veces tocamos esos archivos y hacemos algo que no debemos); 3) hay algunas soluciones aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Comment: Muchas Gracias por las aclaraciones, luego de un intenso estudio del problema, resulto ser un simple descuido de acceder al js. no estaba asignada la ubicacion del  js correctamente en el atributo src. 
Pues el src estaba apuntando a una dirección errónea.